# "Song Cover" in Japanese

Tags: translation

How to you say "song cover" in Japanese. When I see song covers in youtube, the titles have 歌ってみた which, I believe, translates to "tried to sing". So is there no native Japanese way of saying "XYZ song cover" instead of "XYZ 歌カバー"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use カバー, as in ボブ・ディランのカバー or 「少年時代」のカバー. There's no native Japanese word for it as far as I know, I think partly because the notion of "[someone other than the original artist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_version)" is peculiar to modern music scene.

歌ってみた, which I guess is prevalent in [Niconico](http://www.nicovideo.jp/) or wherever, is better translated as "fancover". As you may know, the uploaders are supposed to be of amateur (though not so much these days) fandom who want to sing like their favorite artist, and that's what the word ～みる ("try to do, do a bit") conveys.

Comment: It's worth noting that when the cover is an instrumental cover, i.e. a popular song is played on an instrument like a piano, the verb will change from 歌ってみた (lit. "I tried singing...") to something like 弾いてみた (lit. "I tried playing..."), or whichever verb best suits the instrument.

Answer (score 0):

歌ってみた is just the common way of saying it, like how "Song Cover" is the accepted way in English. Typically, what I see is 【歌ってみた】SONG NAME【ARTIST】, with the special brackets included. It's likely a bit different than what you're used to, but this will net the most traffic since it looks the most natural.